# Can't get the cumulative sum(running total) within a group in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a running total within a group but my current code just gives me an aggregate sum.
For example, my data looks like this

```
  ID      ShiftNum   Status  Type      Rate      HourlyWage       Hours    Total_Amount     
 12542       1        Full    A         1           12.5            40        500
 12542       1        Full    A         1           12.5            35        420
 12542       2        Full    A         1            10             40        400
 12542       2        Full    B         1.2          10             40        480
 17842       1        Full    A         1            11             27        297
 17842       1        Full    B         1.3          11             30        429
```

And what I want is a running total within the same ID, Shift Number, and Status. For example, I want something like this as my final result

```
  ID      ShiftNum   Status  Type      Rate      HourlyWage       Hours    Total_Amount   Running_Tot  
 12542       1        Full    A         1           12.5            40        500            500
 12542       1        Full    A         1           12.5            35        420            920
 12542       2        Full    A         1            10             40        400            400
 12542       2        Full    B         1.2          10             40        480            880
 17842       1        Full    A         1            11             27        297            297
 17842       1        Full    B         1.3          11             30        429            726
```

However, my current code just gives me the total sum within each group. For example, 920, 920 for row 1&2. Here's my code.

```
Select a.*, 
      SUM(Hours) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ShiftNum, Status ORDER BY ID, ShiftNum, Status) as Runnint_Tot
from table a
```

How do I fix my code to get the final result I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate a Running Total in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server)

Comment: @alexsmith5123 . . . You are missing a unique identifier for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an ordering column that uniquely defines each row.  There is not an obvious one in your row, but something like this:

```
SUM(Hours) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ShiftNum, Status ORDER BY hours) as Running_Tot
```

Or:

```
SUM(Hours) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ShiftNum, Status
                 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                ) as Running_Tot
```

The problem you are facing is because the `ORDER BY` keys have ties.  The default window frame is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.  Note the `RANGE`.  That means that all rows with ties are combined.

Also note that there is no utility to including the `PARTITION BY` keys in the `ORDER BY` (well . . . there is one exception in SQL Server if you don't care about the ordering, then including a key can be a handy short-cut).  The ordering occurs *within* a partition.

If your rows can have exact duplicates, I would first suggest that you add a primary key.  But, in the meantime, you could use:

```
with a as (
      select a.*,
             row_number() over (order by id, shiftnum, status) as seqnum
      from tablea a
     )
Select a.*, 
      SUM(Hours) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ShiftNum, Status ORDER BY seqnum) as Running_Tot
from a;
```

The ordering will be arbitrary, but it will at least accumulate.